# How to set the multi sliders in one page?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
var $wrapSlide1 = $('.list_slider1');
    $(".pager .item1 a").hover(function(){
        $wrapSlide1.stop(true).animate({ top:0}, 'fast');  
    });
    $(".pager .item2 a").hover(function(){
        $wrapSlide1.stop(true).animate({ top:-100}, 'fast'); 
    });
    $(".pager .item3 a").hover(function(){
        $wrapSlide1.stop(true).animate({ top:-200}, 'fast'); 
    });
    $(".pager .item4 a").hover(function(){
        $wrapSlide1.stop(true).animate({ top:-300}, 'fast'); 
    });
    $(".pager .item5 a").hover(function(){
        $wrapSlide1.stop(true).animate({ top:-400}, 'fast'); 
    });
```

```css
*{ margin:0; padding:0; list-style:none }

.wrap_slider { position:relative; width:400px; height:100px; margin:0 0 10px 0; overflow:hidden;}

.list_slider1 { position:absolute; top:0; left:0; width:400px; }
.list_slider1 li { height:100px; }
.list_slider1 li .box { height:100px; background:#ccc;}

.pager { position:absolute; top:0; right:0; } 
.pager a { display:block; width:50px; height:19px; margin:0 0 1px 0; text-align:center; color:#fff; font-size:11px;   overflow:hidden; background:#434444 } 
.pager a.active { color:#fff; background:#000}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap_slider"> 
  <ul class="list_slider1">
    <li><div class="box">a1</div></li> 
    <li><div class="box">a2</div></li> 
    <li><div class="box">a3</div></li> 
    <li><div class="box">a4</div></li> 
    <li><div class="box">a5</div></li> 
  </ul> 
  <ul class="pager">
    <li class="item1"><a href="#">show1</a></li>
    <li class="item2"><a href="#">show2</a></li>
    <li class="item3"><a href="#">show3</a></li>
    <li class="item4"><a href="#">show4</a></li>
    <li class="item5"><a href="#">show5</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>  





<div class="wrap_slider"> 
  <ul class="list_slider1">
    <li><div class="box">b1</div></li> 
    <li><div class="box">b2</div></li> 
    <li><div class="box">b3</div></li> 
    <li><div class="box">b4</div></li> 
    <li><div class="box">b5</div></li> 
  </ul> 
  <ul class="pager">
    <li class="item1"><a href="#">show1</a></li>
    <li class="item2"><a href="#">show2</a></li>
    <li class="item3"><a href="#">show3</a></li>
    <li class="item4"><a href="#">show4</a></li>
    <li class="item5"><a href="#">show5</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I have made a slider that when mouseover on pager then slide image. 
I want to use that slider 3 times or more on one page.

The problem is if I use multi slider and when mouseover on pager,  all slider moves same time..  How do I make it  move each own slider?

This is what I tried here 
https://fiddle.jshell.net/wkpjhwag/1/

Comment: Why  don't leverage the usage of *this* . Instead of declaring this at the top var $wrapSlide1 = $('.list_slider1'); just find the .list_slider1 inside the hover event

Comment: Control with id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an update to your code:

```js
$(".pager li a").hover(function() {
  var slider = $(this).closest('.wrap_slider').find('.list_slider1');
  var animateTo = $(this).attr('data-animateto');
  slider.stop(true).animate({
    top: animateTo
  }, 'fast');
});

$('.pager a').hover(function(){   
    $('.pager a').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
 });
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none
}

.wrap_slider {
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0 0 10px 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.list_slider1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 400px;
}

.list_slider1 li {
  height: 100px;
}

.list_slider1 li .box {
  height: 100px;
  background: #ccc;
}

.pager {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.pager a {
  display: block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 19px;
  margin: 0 0 1px 0;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 11px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #434444
}

.pager a.active {
  color: #fff;
  background: #000
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap_slider">
  <ul class="list_slider1">
    <li>
      <div class="box">a1</div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="box">a2</div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="box">a3</div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="box">a4</div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="box">a5</div>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="pager">
    <li class="item1"><a href="#" data-animateto="0">show1</a></li>
    <li class="item2"><a href="#" data-animateto="-100">show2</a></li>
    <li class="item3"><a href="#" data-animateto="-200">show3</a></li>
    <li class="item4"><a href="#" data-animateto="-300">show4</a></li>
    <li class="item5"><a href="#" data-animateto="-400">show5</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>






<div class="wrap_slider">
  <ul class="list_slider1">
    <li>
      <div class="box">b1</div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="box">b2</div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="box">b3</div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="box">b4</div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="box">b5</div>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="pager">
    <li class="item1"><a href="#" data-animateto="0">show1</a></li>
    <li class="item2"><a href="#" data-animateto="-100">show2</a></li>
    <li class="item3"><a href="#" data-animateto="-200">show3</a></li>
    <li class="item4"><a href="#" data-animateto="-300">show4</a></li>
    <li class="item5"><a href="#" data-animateto="-400">show5</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

what i have done is instead or writing a seperate code for each slider function to make the slider work. Have created a single function to call and the parameter to do the navigation is defined in the `html` caller. So, by this way it is a bit more flexible.

> EDIT 1

As for what you have asked, if you want to do that completely from the script side then you need to have an `array` for the `animation` and that has to be mapped with the slides on your page.

So, your script would look like this:

```
//here below is my array which holds the animation values 
var animateTo = [0, -100, -200, -300, -400];
$(".pager li a").hover(function() {             
  var slider = $(this).closest('.wrap_slider').find('.list_slider1');
  var sliderIndex = $(this).parent().index();//index of each slde element
  var animation = animateTo[sliderIndex]; //mapping the slide to its equivalent value in animationTo array
  slider.stop(true).animate({
         top: animation
  }, 'fast');
});
```

Comment: Great thank you.... One more question, If I want put  these attribute  data-animateto=""  to script,  what should I do?  because these value can be change and  I dont want to edit  on HTML file for change values.

Comment: @user3061452 have made an update to my answer please check it.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to make sure that the ID's and classes are unique per slider like this:

HTML:

```
<div class="wrap_slider"> 
    <ul class="list_slider2">
        <li><div class="box">b1</div></li> 
        <li><div class="box">b2</div></li> 
        <li><div class="box">b3</div></li> 
        <li><div class="box">b4</div></li> 
        <li><div class="box">b5</div></li> 
  </ul> 
  <ul class="pager2">
        <li class="item1"><a href="#">show1</a></li>
        <li class="item2"><a href="#">show2</a></li>
        <li class="item3"><a href="#">show3</a></li>
        <li class="item4"><a href="#">show4</a></li>
        <li class="item5"><a href="#">show5</a></li>
  </ul>
```

CSS:

```
*{ margin:0; padding:0; list-style:none }

 .wrap_slider { position:relative; width:400px; height:100px; margin:0 0 
 10px 0; overflow:hidden;}

 .list_slider1,.list_slider2 { position:absolute; top:0; left:0; 
 width:400px; }
 .list_slider1 li,.list_slider2 li { height:100px; }
 .list_slider1 li .box,.list_slider2 li .box { height:100px; 
 background:#ccc;}

 .pager,.pager2 { position:absolute; top:0; right:0; } 
 .pager a,.pager2 a { display:block; width:50px; height:19px; margin:0 0 1px 
 0; text-align:center; color:#fff; font-size:11px;   overflow:hidden; 
 background:#434444 } 
 .pager a.active,.pager2 a.active { color:#fff; background:#000}
```

JavaScript:

```
 var $wrapSlide1 = $('.list_slider1');
$(".pager .item1 a").hover(function(){
    $wrapSlide1.stop(true).animate({ top:0}, 'fast');  
});
$(".pager .item2 a").hover(function(){
    $wrapSlide1.stop(true).animate({ top:-100}, 'fast'); 
});
$(".pager .item3 a").hover(function(){
    $wrapSlide1.stop(true).animate({ top:-200}, 'fast'); 
});
$(".pager .item4 a").hover(function(){
    $wrapSlide1.stop(true).animate({ top:-300}, 'fast'); 
});
$(".pager .item5 a").hover(function(){
    $wrapSlide1.stop(true).animate({ top:-400}, 'fast'); 
});  

var $wrapSlide2 = $('.list_slider2');
$(".pager2 .item1 a").hover(function(){
    $wrapSlide2.stop(true).animate({ top:0}, 'fast');  
});
$(".pager2 .item2 a").hover(function(){
    $wrapSlide2.stop(true).animate({ top:-100}, 'fast'); 
});
$(".pager2 .item3 a").hover(function(){
    $wrapSlide2.stop(true).animate({ top:-200}, 'fast'); 
});
$(".pager2 .item4 a").hover(function(){
    $wrapSlide2.stop(true).animate({ top:-300}, 'fast'); 
});
$(".pager2 .item5 a").hover(function(){
    $wrapSlide2.stop(true).animate({ top:-400}, 'fast'); 
});  

$('.pager a').hover(function(){   
    $('.pager a').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});   
$('.pager2 a').hover(function(){   
    $('.pager2 a').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If reusability is needed here, you should look up how to leverage the use of this context.

This is abit crappy code but you may use this

```
$(".pager .item1 a").hover(function(){
let $wrapSlide1 = $(this).parent().parent().parent().find('.list_slider1');
    $wrapSlide1.stop(true).animate({ top:0}, 'fast');  
});
$(".pager .item2 a").hover(function(){
    var $wrapSlide1 = $(this).parent().parent().parent().find('.list_slider1');
    $wrapSlide1.stop(true).animate({ top:-100}, 'fast'); 
});
$(".pager .item3 a").hover(function(){
    let $wrapSlide1 = $(this).parent().parent().parent().find('.list_slider1');
    $wrapSlide1.stop(true).animate({ top:-200}, 'fast'); 
});
$(".pager .item4 a").hover(function(){
    let $wrapSlide1 = $(this).parent().parent().parent().find('.list_slider1');
    $wrapSlide1.stop(true).animate({ top:-300}, 'fast'); 
});
$(".pager .item5 a").hover(function(){
    let $wrapSlide1 = $(this).parent().parent().parent().find('.list_slider1');
    $wrapSlide1.stop(true).animate({ top:-400}, 'fast'); 
});  

$('.pager a').hover(function(){   
    $('.pager a').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

JS Fiddle here : https://jsfiddle.net/zg9og7re/

Answer (score 0):

Just replace the `$wrapSlide1` with `$(this).closest('div[class^="wrap_slider"]').children(".list_slider1")`

```js
var $wrapSlide1 = $('.list_slider1');
 $(".pager .item1 a").hover(function(){
  $(this).closest('div[class^="wrap_slider"]').children(".list_slider1").stop(true).animate({ top:0}, 'fast');  
 });
 $(".pager .item2 a").hover(function(){        $(this).closest('div[class^="wrap_slider"]').children(".list_slider1").stop(true).animate({ top:-100}, 'fast'); 
 });
 $(".pager .item3 a").hover(function(){
$(this).closest('div[class^="wrap_slider"]').children(".list_slider1").stop(true).animate({ top:-200}, 'fast'); 
 });
 $(".pager .item4 a").hover(function(){
$(this).closest('div[class^="wrap_slider"]').children(".list_slider1").stop(true).animate({ top:-300}, 'fast'); 
 });
 $(".pager .item5 a").hover(function(){
$(this).closest('div[class^="wrap_slider"]').children(".list_slider1").stop(true).animate({ top:-400}, 'fast'); 
 });  
  
 $('.pager a').hover(function(){   
  $('.pager a').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
    });
```

```css
*{ margin:0; padding:0; list-style:none }

.wrap_slider { position:relative; width:400px; height:100px; margin:0 0 10px 0; overflow:hidden;}

.list_slider1 { position:absolute; top:0; left:0; width:400px; }
.list_slider1 li { height:100px; }
.list_slider1 li .box { height:100px; background:#ccc;}

.pager { position:absolute; top:0; right:0; } 
.pager a { display:block; width:50px; height:19px; margin:0 0 1px 0; text-align:center; color:#fff; font-size:11px;   overflow:hidden; background:#434444 } 
.pager a.active { color:#fff; background:#000}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap_slider"> 
  <ul class="list_slider1">
    <li><div class="box">a1</div></li> 
    <li><div class="box">a2</div></li> 
    <li><div class="box">a3</div></li> 
    <li><div class="box">a4</div></li> 
    <li><div class="box">a5</div></li> 
  </ul> 
  <ul class="pager">
    <li class="item1"><a href="#">show1</a></li>
    <li class="item2"><a href="#">show2</a></li>
    <li class="item3"><a href="#">show3</a></li>
    <li class="item4"><a href="#">show4</a></li>
    <li class="item5"><a href="#">show5</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>  


<div class="wrap_slider"> 
  <ul class="list_slider1">
    <li><div class="box">b1</div></li> 
    <li><div class="box">b2</div></li> 
    <li><div class="box">b3</div></li> 
    <li><div class="box">b4</div></li> 
    <li><div class="box">b5</div></li> 
  </ul> 
  <ul class="pager">
    <li class="item1"><a href="#">show1</a></li>
    <li class="item2"><a href="#">show2</a></li>
    <li class="item3"><a href="#">show3</a></li>
    <li class="item4"><a href="#">show4</a></li>
    <li class="item5"><a href="#">show5</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```